# How facebook detect log outs?

Tags: php, facebook

As you seen, while we have 5 open tabs in facebook, once we "Log Out" in one of them and then we go to another tab, it detects that we're logged out and inform us about it and redirect the user to the login page. how this is working? I want to make such thing for my web app with PHP/jQuery. I just need a hint...

Thanks in advance

Comment: It probably just destroys the session/cookie. [session_destroy](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) / [setcookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

Comment: @h2ooooooo this is obvious, but how they check it each 5 seconds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook uses [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) technology on their pages. Every page holds an open HTTP request. As soon as something changes (e.g. "incoming chat message" or in your case "user logged out", this information will be pushed to the clients.

If you're using NGINX as your webserver, I'd suggest to have a look at the [nginx_http_push_module](http://pushmodule.slact.net/)

Answer (score 3):

In the same manner as any other application: when you log out, the server either removes a cookie from the client or changes its value to indicate the "logged out" status. When a new request is made later, the server detects this state in the cookie and returns appropriate content for a logged out user.

Facebook does this with AJAX, but this doesn't change the picture. If you use your browser's developer tools to spy on Facebook's AJAX requests you will be able to see all the gory details.

Comment: What you answered is obvious, but you really think that they're using a simple setTimeOut function to run a function on a time basis? I don't think so! and what if there is no requests? go to a simlpe comments page in fb, and check it there, ty

Comment: @behz4d: They either do that, or they use [long polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) (which is the same mechanism but with a twist). There is no other technology that would work as well for them.

Comment: @behz4d it a long polling technique as Jon said

Answer (score 1):

It most definitely uses [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) requests, which contact the web server in a asynchronous manner (without refreshing the page).

Using the JQuery Library for Ajax requests is pretty simple: [Link to API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: they're not using simple ajax calls with setTimeOut, this is gonna break there system down to do a ajax call each 1 second to million online users I guess!

Comment: Realistically speaking: Facebook is under a constant DDos at all times.

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest ways is to have a Session variable that controls if the user is logged in or not. When you hit log out, it sets that variable to false.

Facebook will have a script routinely calling some kind of ajax call to a server-side script to check the session is still valid. Once it isn't valid, the ajax call will cause the pop-up to appear.